# How does DispatchMessage decide which WndProc to use?

Tags: window, wndproc, procedures

I'm going through some code for an open source project and this is my first time dealing with a Win32 app (mostly did console stuff). I see that several functions within the code are windows procedures because they return LRESULT CALLBACK.

Is there something the programmer has to do to make sure DispatchMessage invokes the right WndProc or is DispatchMessage coded in a way that it can determine the right WndProc all on its own?

---

*EDIT:*

I'm guessing that the way DispatchMessage(const MSG*) chooses between different WndProc's in an application is based on the window handle member (HWND) of the MSG object passed to it.[Hope previous sentence wasn't too confusing.] If the message was for the edit window for an application, for example, (and not for its main window,) then DispatchMessage will choose the WndProc member function for the particular class for which the edit window is an object of. If the message was for the main window, then it would choose the WndProc member function for the class that the main window is an object of (for me, this class would be the Notepad_plus_Window class). This is only a thought, though. I haven't found much to back it up so I'd be glad if anyone could confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, it uses MSG.hwnd to send the message to the correct window. One thing to be noted, it will use the WndProc associated with the window, not the window class. A window is an instance of a window class.

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0397/hood/hood0397.aspx) article of Microsoft's "Under The Hood" illustrates this with rather detailed [pseudo-code](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0397/hood/hoodtextfigs.htm#fig3) of DispatchMessage() that might be worth taking a look as well )

Comment: You said: `it will use the WndProc associated with the window, not the window class`. But how we associate WndProc with window: by window class, that is `wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;`

Comment: Yes, but you can always modify the WndProc for a particular window by calling SetWindowLongPtr. In that case WndProc for the window will be different from the one given for the window class.

Comment: [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description says:
`Calling` **SetWindowLongPtr** `with the` **GWLP_WNDPROC** `index creates a subclass of the window class used to create the window...The` **SetWindowLongPtr** `function creates the window subclass by changing the window procedure associated with a particular window class, causing the system to call the new window procedure instead of the previous one.` This clarifies that one _WndProc_ always associates one _Window Class_. Doesn't it?

Comment: Hello @Vishal, both the links in your answer are broken.